# Where is uc_mcontext definition?

Tags: linux, signals, cpu-registers, signal-handling

The third parameter of sa_sigaction is a pointer which point to a machine-dependent `struct ucontext`, I would like to know what I can dump from `struct ucontext`.

```
void (*sa_sigaction)(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *ucontext)

struct ucontext {
        unsigned long     uc_flags;
        struct ucontext  *uc_link;
        stack_t           uc_stack;
        struct sigcontext uc_mcontext;
        sigset_t          uc_sigmask;   /* mask last for extensibility */
};
```

Particularly through uc_mcontext (if you can show me where I can know more about other data members, that's would be great), as people usually use `uc_mcontext` to dump host registers like this,

```
ucontext->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_EIP]
```

Because `uc_mcontext` type is `struct sigcontext`, I look on `struct sigcontext` in `arch/x86/include/asm/sigcontext.h`.

```
struct sigcontext {
        unsigned short gs, __gsh;
        unsigned short fs, __fsh;
        unsigned short es, __esh;
        unsigned short ds, __dsh;

        ... snip ...
};
```

Is it the right one, beacuse I don't see `gregs` in `struct sigcontext`? Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking at the Linux kernel definition of sigcontext. You should be looking at the C library headers of struct ucontext. It is defined at /usr/include/sys/ucontext.h file

Note that it is architecture  specific - e.g. the fields for x86 and PPC, for example, are totally different!

Comment: Oops, I looked at the wrong place. But why there are two `struct ucontext` defined in kernel and C library?

Comment: @chenwj not sure what is the reason for the duplication

Comment: In my platform, I founded it in this path /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/ucontext.h